# Missing Authorization Header in production only

Tags: python, jwt, flask-jwt-extended, flask-jwt

I have the following work flow:

I have a `api/token` [POST] that takes form-data (email and password) and returns and access token and a refresh token.

Then I have another endpoint `api/users/info` [GET] (with Headers `'Authorization': 'Bearer ...`) that returns user information. When testing locally both endpoints work.

**When testing to my deployed server only the token fetching one works.**

Here is the code for the `api/users/info`:

```
@API_BP.route('/users/info', methods=['GET'])
@fresh_jwt_required
def users_info():

    user_identity = get_jwt_identity()
    curr_user = (SDB.session.query(User)
                 .filter_by(email=user_identity).one_or_none())
    return jsonify({
        'greeting': 'Hello, World!',
        'foo': 'bar',

    })
```

Moreover, here are my configs:

```
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ['cookies', 'headers']
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = True 
JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_NAME = "my_access_cookie"
JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_NAME = "my_refresh_cookie"
JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "my_csrf_access_token"
JWT_REFRESH_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "my_csrf_refresh_token"
JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-MY-TOKEN"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{
    "msg": "Missing JWT in cookies or headers (Missing cookie \"my_access_cookie\"; Missing Authorization Header)"
}
```

I'm using Postman to hit these endpoints. I have the Token received by `api/token` set under authorization. Here is what that looks like in python:

```
import requests

url = "http://my_url.com/api/users/info"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhrtyuzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MjU5MTg0MTEsIm5iZiI6MTYyNTkxODQxMSwianRpfghZi00YTcyLWIxZTYtZGMxYTRjNDhkOThhIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI1OTE5NjExLCJpZGVudGl0eSI6ImFsZnJlZG9Adml2ZWJlbmVmaXRzLmNvbSIsImZyZXNoIjp0cnVlLCsdfghXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiY3NyZiI6ImQyNTQ0NjY0LTFlOGUtNDY5NS1hY2I4LTE2MzIxMDZlNDY0MiJ9.WT-EWlMtZZKoNyiXYxa3xdfghjg7r7ys'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

What can I do to ensure the second request `GET` works in prod?

Comment: Which REST API client are you using? postman? can you remove all cookies in it?

Comment: You used Bearer token in the bottom code, while in your config you have `JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_NAME = "my_access_cookie"` can you make sure they match

Comment: I am using postman to hit these endpoints. Again the discrepancy happens when sending to localhost/prod. It works in local not in prod. I have cleared all cookies.
For the second comment what do you mean ? Replace Bearer with `my_access_cookie `?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Comment: I tried that. No change. I'm pretty sure that config only matters when trying to access endpoints via cookies, not header

Comment: I am viewing the docs  [https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/examples/jwt_locations.py] now, and it seems the jwt decorator has been changed to @jwt_required, did you try to use @jwt_required(locations=["headers"]), as described in https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/examples/jwt_locations.py?

Comment: I think the issue might be that in my request headers, I do not have an `Authorization` header, I only have an `X-Forwarded-Authorization` What would be the best way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `verify_jwt_in_request()` would look for the header `Authorization` instead of `X-Forwarded-Authorization`.

Locally, the header would be `Authorization` but in production, because we are using docker/nginx, the header changes to `X-Forwarded-Authorization`. The way I fixed this was to set the config `JWT_HEADER_NAME = "X-Forwarded-Authorization"`

Answer (score 3):

If you’re using modwsgi in production you will probably need to make sure you have the `WSGIPAssAuthorization On` configuration option enabled. There might be similar options depending on what software you are using to run the flask app in prod (Apache/nginx/uwsgi/unicorn/etc).

Comment: I submitted an answer, do you think its related ? As in if I would set `WSGIPAssAuthorization On` would the Header not transform from `Authorization` -> `X-Forwarded-Authorization` ?

Comment: Worked for me. I added `WSGIPassAuthorization On` on _/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf_ in this file.